# Node.js as a JSON forwarder

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, node.js

I'm new to Node.js but I wanted to use it as a quick web server which would simply take in a request uri and then run a query on an internal service which returns a JSON stream.

I.e. something like this:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  if(uri === "/streamA") {
    //send get request to internal network server http://server:1234/db?someReqA -->Returns JSON ....?
    //send response to requestor of the JSON from the above get ....?
  }
  else if(uri === "/streamB") {
    //send get request to internal network server http://server:1234/db?someReqB -->Returns JSON ....?
    //send response to requestor of the JSON from the above get....?
}.listen(8080);
```

I'm using the newest stable version of node.js - version 0.4.12. I was hoping this would be very easy to do however, I havent been able to find some examples on the net as they all seem to use an old API version so I'm getting error after error.

Would anyone be able to provide a code solution to the above that works with the new Node APIs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a code that should explain your task:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url')

var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/' //Make sure path is escaped
}; //Options for getting the remote page

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  if(uri === "/streamA") {
    http.get(options, function(res) {

        res.pipe( response ); //Everything from the remote page is written into the response
        //The connection is also auto closed

    }).on('error', function(e) {
        response.writeHead( 500 ); //Internal server error
        response.end( "Got error " + e); //End the request with this message
    });

  } else {
    response.writeHead( 404 ); //Could not find it
    response.end("Invalid request");

  }

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thanks Nican, this works when I have a path like `path: '/db?'` but when I change this to a different path like this one `path: '/db?{\"SQL\":\"SELECT * FROM classifier_results_summary\"}' ` I get a socket hang up - res is not defined, any idea why?

Comment: Update again - use the path : escape('myUrl') function to make sure the path is URL safe...

Comment: The escape function used is the generic javascript library one - see doco here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: I would be very careful with anything from that site.

Comment: @NightWolf please, don't do that. Read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

And here's instead of w3schools:

https://developer.mozilla.org/

Comment: @Linus,yes this is clearly not prod code. Thanks for the tips. We do all formatting in JS and rebuild the query on the node side to avoid these issues. Node is great for this task and it means we can easily move of infra where ever needed.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [express](http://expressjs.com), it would make it a lot easier.

```
var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/json1', function(req, res){
  var json // = 
  res.send(json);
});

app.get('/json2', function(req, res){
  var json // = 
  res.send(json);
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Express looks very helpful, but from reading the doco its as clear as mud how I would acutally do a json get from another server....

Comment: You could just use request https://github.com/mikeal/request as such `request('http://', function (error, response, body){ res.send(body) })`

Answer (score 2):

Ok since this question has a number of up-votes it would seem others are interested in it as well. While Nican's answer was the most helpful for getting actual JSON, I decided that my solution would use both the http lib and express as suggested by 3on as I really like its simplicity...

So for those interested my final solution was a combo of the two:

```
var http = require("http"),
    url = require("url");

var app = require('express').createServer();    
app.listen(9898);

var query = {"SQL" : "SELECT * FROM classifier_results_summary"};
var options = { 
  host: 'issa', 
  port: 9090, 
  path: '/db?'+ escape(JSON.stringify(query))
}; //Options for getting the remote page 

   app.get('/stream/:id', function(req, res){
        //console.log(options.path);
        http.get(options, function(response) { 
        response.pipe( res ); //Everything from the remote page is written into the response 
            //The connection is also auto closed 
        }).on('error', function(e) { 
            response.writeHead( 500 ); //Internal server error 
            response.end( "Got error " + e); //End the request with this message 
        }); 
    });
```

Very nice and neat. Thanks for the help all.